# How to find inconsistency in data?

Tags: feature-engineering, anomaly-detection

I wonder how I can find any inconsistencies in data. To show what I mean let's consider the following example:

Imagine I have a problem of finding out why the speed (S) of the vehicle is low. I have following features : rotation speed (RS), rotation number (RN), type of road (TR). The target speed (S) is calculated is RS * RN. The type of road (TR) fixes the maximum possible rotation speed (RS) with mapping {1 : 100, 2 : 150, 3 : 200}. There is sample from dataset:

```
RS   RN   TR   S
98   2    1    196
199  1    3    199
147  3    2    441
60   2    1    120
```

I want my model to highlight the last object because value of RS is 60 whereas maximum possible value for its type of road is 100. So speed for that object potentially can be increased. How can I achieve that? And of course in real dataset such dependencies are unknown and could be much more complicated than in that example. I've tried to create models which are fitted with separate features as targets and to predict (with and without initial target (S) as feature) but it didn't show good results. What approaches may I try?

Comment: This does not seem to be a predictive model as there is nothing probabilistic and no target defined. This seems to be a rule or maybe a few rules. There is mention the problem gets more complicated so do those have targets?

Comment: @Craig Why not? If define one of the features as target and try to predict it, everything seems correct? In addition, if you consider tree models, they are too just set of different rules

Comment: What is the target? I think from the example the target is if RS < S given the value of TR. And is this a probabilistic prediction vs a set of rules. Trees are a set of rules but created from minimizing a loss function and out at the bottom is a prediction (probability or log-odds). From my reading, this seems like a set of rules that can deterministically say Yes or No.

Comment: @Craig, the target of the initial data is `S`. But my goal is to find objects where `S` can be higher than it is now. In current approach it creates subtask for every feature, where this feature becomes target. We try to predict it and if predicted feature is higly different from existing feature, that could be the reason of low `S`.